# How can I make it so that a control is visible only if a binding value is not an empty space?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML:

```
<t:FooterTemplate Text="{Binding SourceFooter }" />
```

The object has margins and color.

How can I make it so that it's not visible using the IsVisible, if the value of SourceFooter = "" ?

I want to do something like:

```
<t:FooterTemplate Text="{Binding SourceFooter }" IsVisible="{ SourceFooter != "" }" />
```

But I know that's not possible to do.

Comment: either bind it to SourceFooter with a ValueConverter, or add a bool property to your VM that checks is SourceFooter is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Option: Converter**

You can use a converter for this. For example:

```
 <t:FooterTemplate Text="{Binding SourceFooter }" IsVisible="{Binding SourceFooter, Converter={StaticResource StringEmptyConverter} }" />
```

And then the converter looks like this:

```
    public class StringEmptyConverter : IValueConverter {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((string)value));
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The converter simply returns false if the string is whitespace or null.

To use it as a StaticResource, of course you'll also have to add a line in the ResourceDictionary in the App.xaml file.

```
            <converters:StringEmptyConverter x:Key="StringEmptyConverter" />
```

**Second option: [DataTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=netframework-4.7.2)**

Triggers can modify the properties of the visual element. As the name says: they are triggered when a certain property (`SourceFooter`) equals a certain value (`""`).

```
<t:FooterTemplate Text="{Binding SourceFooter}" >
 <t:FooterTemplate.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger
    Binding="{Binding SourceFooter}"
    TargetType="t:FooterTemplate"
    Value="">
        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="false" />
    </DataTrigger>
 </t:FooterTemplate.Triggers>
</t:FooterTemplate>
```

**What do I use?**

In this case you should go for the `Converter` solution. You're probably gonna be checking if a string is empty somewhere else in your app. 
In my opinion, DataTriggers can be useful for more exotic 'Triggers'.